# Can I configure a DNS cache not to forward AAAA queries?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, internal-dns

I'm setting up an internal DNS cache because my firewall is having trouble handling all the sessions created by DNS requests. I tried using bind9, dnsmasq and DJB dnscache, they all help reduce the number of requests leaving my network, but there are still a lot of request being made.

Looking at the log files, and tcpdump and dnstop outputs, it seems that requests that return SERVFAIL do not get cached at all. And a lot of those failed requests are AAAA requests, which is a shame, because I do not have ipv6 enabled on any server.

I've looked at several ways to help the situation, and I think if I could somehow prevent AAAA record requests from being forwarded by the DNS cache, it would reduce the number of requests significantly.

The closest thing I found was the [filter-aaaa-on-v4](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00576/) option in BIND9. However, this only removes the record from the server response, and does not prevent it from forwarding it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: bind9 have some filtering feature called RPZ - responce policy zones. Maybe it will do for you...

Comment: @Sandman4 From what I could gather, RPZ does not have a mechanism for filtering by record type. Interesting read, though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible in any standard DNS resolver. Besides: hiding the IPv6 responses from clients might break DNSSEC validation, depending on if/where you validate.

An authoritative DNS server should not return a SERVFAIL when asked for data it doesn't have, so the real problem is those servers. I personally see such bad behaviour very rarely, but you seem to see it more often. If there are just a few servers that misbehave like this it might be a good idea to let the operator or the domain name holders know so they can fix it.

Some firewalls can process certain traffic stateless. You could filter like

```
internal DNS cache address port > 1024  <-->  * port 53
```

and make all that traffic stateless. You won't lose much protection and your firewall will have a lower load. To be honest I am surprised that your firewall has problems with handling DNS query sessions. You never specified which brand and model you are using. I did this on a Juniper SRX 210 for a BitTorrent server. If you think DNS requests cause many sessions... ;-)

And if all else fails you could move the work to an external DNS resolver. If you configure your DNS cache to forward all queries to an external resolver (your ISP's resolvers and 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 come to mind) then your DNS cache won't have to walk the DNS tree itself, which will lower the number of queries a lot.